# convolution using a 3X3 low pass filter for a .pgm image in C++

Tags: c++, image, convolution

I'm trying to write a program in C++ which has following 3 functions:
(i) read_pgm_image() - to read the image in .pgm format from a file;
(ii) convolve() - to perform convolution on the image using a 3X3 low pass filter; and,
(iii) write_pgm_image() - to write the image data back into a separate file

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void read_pgm_image(char name[]);
void convolve(int img[][256], int M, int N, int img_intensity);
void write_pgm_image(char name[], int img[256][256], int img_data[]);

int main()
{   read_pgm_image("lenna2.pgm");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void read_pgm_image(char name[])
{   string magic, creator_info;
    int img_intensity, M, N;
    ifstream file(name, ios::binary);
    if(file.is_open())
    {   cout<<"File successfully opened! \n\n";
        cout<<"Reading the file...\n";
        cout<<"Name of the file:\t"<<name<<'\n';

        getline(file,magic); // get the magic number

        getline(file,creator_info); // get the creator information

        file>>M; // get width of the image
        cout<<"Width of the Image:\t"<<M<<'\n';

        file>>N; // get length of the image
        cout<<"Length of the Image:\t"<<N<<'\n';

        file>>img_intensity; // get the image intensity
        cout<<"Maximum Intensity:\t"<<img_intensity<<'\n'; 

        int img[256][256]; // create an array to store image data
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {   for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
            {   file.read((char*)&img[i][j],sizeof(int));
            }
        }
        file.close();

        convolve(img, M, N, img_intensity); // Calling the Convolve function
    }
    else
    {   cout<<"Error in opening image!";
        file.close();
    }
}



void convolve(int img[256][256], int M, int N, int img_intensity)
{   int con_img[256][256], sum=0, img_data[3]={M,N,img_intensity};

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {   for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
        {   con_img[i][j]=img[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=1; i<(N-1); i++)
{   for(int j=1; j<(M-1); j++)
    {   for(int k=(i-1); k<(i+1); k++)
        {   for(int l=(j-1); l<(j+1); l++)
            {   sum = sum + img[k][l];
            }
        }
        con_img[i][j] = sum/9;
        sum=0;
    }
}

write_pgm_image("image_convolve.pgm", con_img, img_data);
}



void write_pgm_image(char name[], int img[256][256], int img_data[3])
{ cout<<"\nCreating image file...\n";

  ofstream file(name,ios::binary);

  if(file.is_open())
  {   cout<<"File successfully created!\n";
      cout<<"Writing image data...\n";

      file<<"P5\n"<<img_data[0]<<' '<<img_data[1]<<' '<<img_data[2]; //Writing P5, image width, image length and maximum intensity

      cout<<"Image data written!\n";

      for(int i=0; i<img_data[1]; i++)  //Write image data to the file
        {   for(int j=0; j<img_data[0]; j++)
            {   file.write((char*)&(img[i][j]), sizeof(int));
            }
        }
      cout<<"Image pixel info written!\n";
      file.close();
  }
  else
  { cout <<"Error in creating file!";
    file.close();
  }
}
```

There seems to be some problem in the convolve() function. Ideally, I should be getting a blurred version of input image (which I'm not able to upload). But I'm getting a garbage image instead.

Any help is much appreciated...
Thank you.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "garbage". Your convolution function looks fine except for the small bug elias pointed out. Does the output image nothing like the input image? If not, the problem is probably in your file reader/writer, or both. The PGM file specifiation says that pixels intensities are given either **1 or 2 bytes** of memory, yet you are reading in bytes 4 at a time since `sizeof(int) == 4`. You should try printing out some pixel values after you read the image to see if they are what you expect.

Comment: If I saved the image just after reading the original image (i.e. call the write_pgm_image() function in read_pgm_image() function before calling the convolve() function, I get the exact same image - which is expected. It is the same case if I call the write function in convolve function before performing any operations.

Comment: However, I tried one thing. If I assign a particular value (for e.g. 0 or 255 or -1) to an element in the 2D array con_img[][], then this happens. If I assign 0 or positive value, I get a black pixel. If I assign a negative value, I get a white pixel. This is the what I mean by getting a 'garbage' image.

Comment: In the file.read and file.write lines, I changed sizeof(int) to (sizeof(int)/4). This seems to be working. I am getting a blurred image for most part of the image. However, in the last 7 rows (7 rows from the bottom), I'm still getting 'garbage'. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `img` to be a 2D array of integers, that is to say every entry in the array is 4 bytes. You are also reading the file 4 bytes at a time using `sizeof(int)`.

```
 int img[256][256]; // create an array to store image data
 for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
 {   for(int j=0; j<M; j++)
     {   file.read((char*)&img[i][j],sizeof(int));
     }
 }
```

According to the [PGM file specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html), pixel values are either **1 or 2 bytes**, (either `char` or `shorts`) depending on whether the max intensity value is larger than 255. You are reading either 2 or 4 pixel values from the file into 1 entry in your `img` array.

Your file reader should look more liked this. We can read the file in all at once since both C++ and PGM arrays store data in row-major order.

```
char img[N][M];
file.ignore(); // ignore one character (as described in file specification)
file.read((char*)img,(streamsize)sizeof(img));
```

---

If it still isn't working, make sure you can reproduce the results of this PGM file `test.pgm`:

```
P5
# this is a comment
5 5
255
!!!!!AAAAA~~~~~AAAAA!!!!!
```

Printing out the matrix gives these values:

```
33 33 33 33 33 
65 65 65 65 65 
126 126 126 126 126 
65 65 65 65 65 
33 33 33 33 33
```

The image viewer on my computer displays it like this (zoomed in 2000%):

[image]

Comment: I have changed the code. Instead of inputting pixel values as int, I'm taking them as char. This seems to be working perfectly fine.
Thanks a lot eigenchris!

Comment: @pras Glad to hear it. You might consider accepting or upvoting the answer if you feel it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a small bug with the loop boundaries for k and l (< should be <=), so you are summing up 4 pixels instead of 9. You are dividing with 9 later to get the average, which would be correct if you added up the correct number of pixels, but the sum is already flawed.

Comment: Thanks elias for pointing out the bug. I'm still getting a 'garbage' image even after correcting the bug that you pointed out.